# How to find Difference distribution table of DES S box?

Tags: cryptanalysis, des

I Have used Sage command

```
sage: S = SBox(14,4,13,1,2,15,11,8,3,10,6,12,5,9,0,7)
sage: S.difference_distribution_table()
the output is 
[16  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  2  0  0  0  2  0  2  4  0  4  2  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  2  0  6  2  2  0  2  0  0  0  0  2  0]
[ 0  0  2  0  2  0  0  0  0  4  2  0  2  0  0  4]
[ 0  0  0  2  0  0  6  0  0  2  0  4  2  0  0  0]
[ 0  4  0  0  0  2  2  0  0  0  4  0  2  0  0  2]
[ 0  0  0  4  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  2  2  2]
[ 0  0  2  2  2  0  2  0  0  2  2  0  0  0  0  4]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  2  2  0  0  0  4  0  4  2  2]
[ 0  2  0  0  2  0  0  4  2  0  2  2  2  0  0  0]
[ 0  2  2  0  0  0  0  0  6  0  0  2  0  0  4  0]
[ 0  0  8  0  0  2  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  2]
[ 0  2  0  0  2  2  2  0  0  0  0  2  0  6  0  0]
[ 0  4  0  0  0  0  0  4  2  0  2  0  2  0  2  0]
[ 0  0  2  4  2  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  2  0]
[ 0  2  0  0  6  0  0  0  0  4  0  2  0  0  2  0]
```

This output is produced from one first line of S box. How to find the difference table of the whole S box

Comment: The module only works [square sboxes](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/cryptography/sage/crypto/sboxes.html#module-sage.crypto.sboxes). You can benefit [this answers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/30173/18298) or ask at https://ask.sagemath.org/

Comment: I wanted to know the method for rectangular S boxes like DES. Has anyone gone through this type of problem before. Thank in advance